# Magento 2.1 google analytics, IP anonymization

Tags: magento-2.1

How can I make the google analytics code IP anonymous?

like this

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'anonymizeIp': true
});
```

In the code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the free extension [Magento 2 Google Analytics Ecommerce](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-analytics-pro/) which works like a charm.`Enable IP Anonymization` feature is available in this extension which may work for you.

Comment: i think its not free

Comment: Sorry. You may try this extension [Fooman Google Analytics](https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-googleanalyticsplus-m2.html) . Another [Extension by Welt](https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html). There is a free version of it which has the IP anonymization feature. You may try your luck with these extensions.